# JMeter & Gitlab: How to Install & SQLServer JDBC Driver?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, gitlab-ci-runner, mssql-jdbc, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a Gitlab pipeline that calls JMeter from the `justb4/jmeter:latest` Docker image.

Everything was working fine, but then I forgot when I checked in the latest version of my JMX that I was using the MSSQL JDBC driver which is installed locally, so I get the expected ClassNotFoundException below.

What is the/a correct way to make the relevant DLL and JAR available to my gitlab-ci file?

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:462)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:528)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:362)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:198)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) needs to be present in the image you're deploying so you need to create your own Docker image based on the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/Dockerfile) from the `justb4/jmeter:latest` and add one more line to it between

```
&& tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
```

and

```
&& rm -rf /tmp/dependencies
```

you need to add something like:

```
&& curl -L --silent https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.4.1.jre8/mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar >  /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib  \
```

Then you need to:

- [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the image
- [tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) it using your own image name/version
- [push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) it to dockerhub
- replace `justb4/jmeter:latest` with your own image tag:version

Going forward be aware that you can build a JMeter docker image from scratch yourself without having to rely on other people images, see [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for comprehensive information.

Comment: For the next reader's convenience, you would also add this if you want Windows Authentication:    `&& curl -L --silent https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc_auth/9.4.1.x86/mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll >  /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib  \`