# JMeter & the JDBC Driver Using Docker - "DBCP DataSource configured without a 'password'" mssql

Tags: sql-server, docker, jdbc, jmeter, gitlab

This is based on the answer in [JMeter & Gitlab: How to Install & SQLServer JDBC Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70589102/jmeter-gitlab-how-to-install-sqlserver-jdbc-driver).

In short, the debug output below shows that the appropriate JAR and DLL are in the Java-path on the Docker image, yet I am seeing the following error in the JMeter output:

- "DBCP DataSource configured without a 'password'" mssql
- "DBCP DataSource configured without a 'user'" mssql

The image uses JMeter 5.4.2 ("latest").

The JDBC driver files I am using are:

- mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll
- mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar

So is it a compatibility issue?

I have JMeter 5.4.1 installed on my computer, and the test plan works fine using the local application.

Here is the output from the Gitlab job:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
[0;m[0K  on qaildk03 VFwBJtXZ
[0;msection_start:1641760700:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image guythedocker/jmeter_mssql:latest ...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image guythedocker/jmeter_mssql:latest ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image sha256:7ebf2689ca4b15d4053c8148055524bfaf8173b76d2d66f45d0a13ce6992b901 for guythedocker/jmeter_mssql:latest with digest guythedocker/jmeter_mssql@sha256:316e3ce3f37c174147b10ce541e66121a4d5017f597f862b64cb081fae4035b8 ...
[0;msection_end:1641760705:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1641760705:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m
[0;mRunning on runner-vfwbjtxz-project-516-concurrent-0 via qaildk03...
section_end:1641760707:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1641760707:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m
[0;m[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 50...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/guyl/api-performance-test/.git/
[32;1mChecking out 89b301b5 as develop...[0;m
Removing public/
Removing testresults/

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1641760709:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1641760709:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m
[0;m[32;1m$ ls /opt/apache-jmeter-*/lib/[0;m

etc

mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar                    <------------------
mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll                <------------------

etc


[32;1m$ env[0;m
CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE=guyl
GITLAB_USER_ID=128
CI_RUNNER_VERSION=13.5.0
FF_SKIP_NOOP_BUILD_STAGES=true
LYNX_OP_USERS=50
CI_SERVER_NAME=GitLab
CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=qaildk03
GITLAB_USER_EMAIL=guyl@xxxx.com
CI_SERVER_REVISION=4469fca16f1
CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH=linux/amd64
CI_REGISTRY_USER=gitlab-ci-token
CI_API_V4_URL=https://gitlab.xxxx.net/api/v4
CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=[MASKED]
CI_RUNNER_SHORT_TOKEN=VFwBJtXZ
CI_JOB_NAME=api test
HOSTNAME=runner-vfwbjtxz-project-516-concurrent-0
GITLAB_USER_LOGIN=guyl
OCTO_KEY=[MASKED]
CI_PROJECT_NAME=api-performance-test
CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=schedule
CI_BUILD_REF_NAME=develop
CI_JOB_STATUS=running
MONYX_LOOPS=100
FF_SHELL_EXECUTOR_USE_LEGACY_PROCESS_KILL=false
CI_PIPELINE_ID=74075
CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG=develop
CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=develop
CI_SERVER=yes
CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=89b301b5
FF_CMD_DISABLE_DELAYED_ERROR_LEVEL_EXPANSION=false
CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX=gitlab.xxxx.net:443/guyl/dependency_proxy/containers
PWD=/builds/guyl/api-performance-test
CI_RUNNER_TAGS=
CI_PROJECT_PATH=guyl/api-performance-test
RAMPUP=
CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE=/builds/guyl/api-performance-test.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
MOMA2_LOOPS=0
TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
FF_RESET_HELPER_IMAGE_ENTRYPOINT=true
CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED=true
CI_SERVER_VERSION_MINOR=8
CI_COMMIT_SHA=89b301b5c6370b45bbd7770e1d827fa334a5300d
HOME=/root
FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD=false
CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_PASSWORD=[MASKED]
CI_PROJECT_VISIBILITY=internal
CI_CONCURRENT_PROJECT_ID=0
JMETER_HOME=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.2                         <------------------------
CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE=Update .gitlab-ci.yml file
USERS=
CI_BUILD_NAME=api test
FF_USE_DIRECT_DOWNLOAD=true
CI_PAGES_DOMAIN=gitlab-pages.xxxx.net
CI_SERVER_VERSION=13.8.6
CI_SERVER_PORT=443
CURRENT_VERSION=10.2
MOMA2_USERS=2
JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.2.tgz
CI_PAGES_URL=https://guyl.gitlab-pages.xxxx.net/api-performance-test
CI_PIPELINE_IID=238
CI_REPOSITORY_URL=https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.xxxx.net/guyl/api-performance-test.git
CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.xxxx.net
GITLAB_FEATURES=
ENGINE_LOOPS=100
CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION=
MOMA2_RAMPUP=6
CI_JOB_STAGE=test
CI_PIPELINE_URL=https://gitlab.xxxx.net/guyl/api-performance-test/-/pipelines/74075
ENGINE_RAMPUP=9
CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH=develop
ENGINE_USERS=0
CI_BUILD_REF=89b301b5c6370b45bbd7770e1d827fa334a5300d
CI_SERVER_VERSION_PATCH=6
CI_COMMIT_TITLE=Update .gitlab-ci.yml file
CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE=guyl
MONYX_USERS=100
GITLAB_USER_NAME=Guy Levin
CI_PROJECT_DIR=/builds/guyl/api-performance-test
LYNX_OP_LOOPS=0
SHLVL=2
CI_RUNNER_ID=24
CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP=2022-01-09T20:36:44+00:00
CI_DISPOSABLE_ENVIRONMENT=true
CI_JOB_JWT=[MASKED]
CI_BUILD_ID=169407
CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
LYNX_OP_RAMPUP=25
JMETER_BIN=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.2/bin                        <---------------------------------
CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=develop
CI_SERVER_HOST=gitlab.xxxx.net
CI_JOB_URL=https://gitlab.xxxx.net/guyl/api-performance-test/-/jobs/169407
CI_JOB_TOKEN=[MASKED]
CI_CONCURRENT_ID=0
CI_BUILD_TOKEN=[MASKED]
CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=develop
FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY=true
CI_RUNNER_REVISION=ece86343
CI_BUILD_BEFORE_SHA=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_USER=gitlab-ci-token
MONYX_RAMPUP=0
CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG=guyl-api-performance-test
CI_PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH=.gitlab-ci.yml
CI_NODE_TOTAL=1
CI_BUILDS_DIR=/builds
CI_JOB_ID=169407
CI_PROJECT_REPOSITORY_LANGUAGES=javascript,batchfile
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.2/bin     <-------------
CI_PROJECT_ID=516
CI=true
GITLAB_CI=true
CI_JOB_IMAGE=guythedocker/jmeter_mssql:latest
CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
CI_PROJECT_TITLE=api-performance-test
CI_SERVER_VERSION_MAJOR=13
CI_CONFIG_PATH=.gitlab-ci.yml
CI_BUILD_STAGE=test
CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_SERVER=gitlab.xxxx.net:443
CI_PROJECT_URL=https://gitlab.xxxx.net/guyl/api-performance-test
OLDPWD=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.2
_=/usr/bin/env
[32;1m$ echo $PATH[0;m
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.2/bin          <-----------
[32;1m$ /entrypoint.sh --version[0;m
START Running Jmeter on Sun Jan  9 21:38:30 CET 2022
JVM_ARGS=-Xmn502m -Xms2008m -Xmx2008m
jmeter args=--version
jmeter ALL ARGS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true --version
Jan 09, 2022 9:38:32 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
    _    ____   _    ____ _   _ _____       _ __  __ _____ _____ _____ ____
   / \  |  _ \ / \  / ___| | | | ____|     | |  \/  | ____|_   _| ____|  _ \
  / _ \ | |_) / _ \| |   | |_| |  _|    _  | | |\/| |  _|   | | |  _| | |_) |
 / ___ \|  __/ ___ \ |___|  _  | |___  | |_| | |  | | |___  | | | |___|  _ <
/_/   \_\_| /_/   \_\____|_| |_|_____|  \___/|_|  |_|_____| |_| |_____|_| \_\ 5.4.2

Copyright (c) 1999-2021 The Apache Software Foundation

END Running Jmeter on Sun Jan  9 21:38:33 CET 2022
[32;1m$ mkdir testresults[0;m
[32;1m$ mkdir testresults/monyx[0;m
[32;1m$ mkdir testresults/moma2[0;m
[32;1m$ mkdir testresults/lynx_operational[0;m
[32;1m$ mkdir testresults/engine[0;m
[32;1m$ /entrypoint.sh -n -t ./JMeter/Monyx_API/Monyx_API.jmx -l ./monyx.log -e -o ./testresults/monyx -Jthreads=$MONYX_USERS -Jrampup=$MONYX_RAMPUP -JtestCases=$MONYX_LOOPS -Jhost=qa2-payapi.xxxx.com -f  # collapsed multi-line command[0;m
START Running Jmeter on Sun Jan  9 21:38:33 CET 2022
JVM_ARGS=-Xmn502m -Xms2008m -Xmx2008m
jmeter args=-n -t ./JMeter/Monyx_API/Monyx_API.jmx -l ./monyx.log -e -o ./testresults/monyx -Jthreads=100 -Jrampup=0 -JtestCases=100 -Jhost=qa2-payapi.xxxx.com -f
jmeter ALL ARGS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -n -t ./JMeter/Monyx_API/Monyx_API.jmx -l ./monyx.log -e -o ./testresults/monyx -Jthreads=100 -Jrampup=0 -JtestCases=100 -Jhost=qa2-payapi.xxxx.com -f
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using ./JMeter/Monyx_API/Monyx_API.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Sun Jan 09 21:38:35 CET 2022 (1641760715608)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +  13617 in 00:01:23 =  163.8/s Avg:   577 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (73.44%) Active: 100 Started: 300 Finished: 200
summary +   5932 in 00:00:30 =  197.2/s Avg:   503 Min:   256 Max:  1501 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 98 Started: 300 Finished: 202
summary =  19549 in 00:01:53 =  172.7/s Avg:   555 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (51.15%)
summary +    489 in 00:00:31 =   15.7/s Avg:  2068 Min:   251 Max: 28079 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 100 Started: 400 Finished: 300
summary =  20038 in 00:02:24 =  138.7/s Avg:   591 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (49.91%)
summary +     93 in 00:00:30 =    3.1/s Avg: 30500 Min: 19297 Max: 47158 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 100 Started: 400 Finished: 300
summary =  20131 in 00:02:54 =  115.7/s Avg:   730 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (49.67%)
summary +     96 in 00:00:34 =    2.8/s Avg: 34369 Min: 22688 Max: 45334 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 100 Started: 400 Finished: 300
summary =  20227 in 00:03:28 =   97.3/s Avg:   889 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (49.44%)
summary +     79 in 00:00:25 =    3.1/s Avg: 35523 Min: 23972 Max: 45774 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 100 Started: 400 Finished: 300
summary =  20306 in 00:03:53 =   87.1/s Avg:  1024 Min:     5 Max: 49132 Err: 10000 (49.25%)
summary +     81 in 00:00:33 =    2.4/s Avg: 36941 Min: 24322 Max: 46364 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 100 Started: 400 Finished: 300

etc

summary =  63674 in 01:35:23 =   11.1/s Avg:  8779 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 18594 (29.20%)
summary +    613 in 00:00:30 =   20.4/s Avg:  4952 Min:     0 Max: 15629 Err:   204 (33.28%) Active: 100 Started: 600 Finished: 500
summary =  64287 in 01:35:53 =   11.2/s Avg:  8742 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 18798 (29.24%)
DBCP DataSource configured without a 'username'
DBCP DataSource configured without a 'password'

etc
DBCP DataSource configured without a 'password'
DBCP DataSource configured without a 'username'
DBCP DataSource configured without a 'password'
DBCP DataSource configured withosummary +    377 in 00:00:30 =   12.6/s Avg:  7965 Min:   810 Max: 15971 Err:   188 (49.87%) Active: 100 Started: 1700 Finished: 1600
summary = 257193 in 02:40:23 =   26.7/s Avg:  3659 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 61102 (23.76%)
summary +    388 in 00:00:30 =   12.9/s Avg:  7759 Min:   786 Max: 15878 Err:   191 (49.23%) Active: 100 Started: 1700 Finished: 1600



etc



summary +   3850 in 00:00:30 =  128.3/s Avg:   715 Min:    24 Max:  1653 Err:  3850 (100.00%) Active: 100 Started: 2700 Finished: 2600
summary = 383734 in 03:09:53 =   33.7/s Avg:  2835 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 164923 (42.98%)
summary +   3864 in 00:00:30 =  128.7/s Avg:   765 Min:    44 Max:  3479 Err:  3864 (100.00%) Active: 100 Started: 2700 Finished: 2600
summary = 387598 in 03:10:23 =   33.9/s Avg:  2814 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 168787 (43.55%)
summary +   2405 in 00:00:19 =  128.8/s Avg:   707 Min:    24 Max:  1436 Err:  2405 (100.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
summary = 390003 in 03:10:42 =   34.1/s Avg:  2801 Min:     0 Max: 114698 Err: 171192 (43.90%)
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Jan 10 00:49:18 CET 2022 (1641772158705)
... end of run
END Running Jmeter on Mon Jan 10 00:49:44 CET 2022
```

And here is the Dockerfile:

```
# inspired by https://github.com/hauptmedia/docker-jmeter  and
# https://github.com/hhcordero/docker-jmeter-server/blob/master/Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.12

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.2"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL  https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz

# Install extra packages
# Set TimeZone, See: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136#issuecomment-612751142
ARG TZ="Europe/Amsterdam"
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  

RUN tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt

RUN mkdir -p ${JMETER_HOME}/lib

RUN curl --ssl-no-revoke -L https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.4.1.jre8/mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar -o mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar 
RUN curl --ssl-no-revoke -L https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc_auth/9.4.1.x86/mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll -o mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll
    
RUN rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

COPY ./mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib/
COPY ./mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib/

# TODO: plugins (later)
# && unzip -oq "/tmp/dependencies/JMeterPlugins-*.zip" -d $JMETER_HOME

# Set global PATH such that "jmeter" command is found
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

# Entrypoint has same signature as "jmeter" command
COPY entrypoint.sh /


WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

[image]

JMeter Report, showing errors:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use [SQL Server integrated authentication from Linux machine.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication)

In order to be able to use the approach with the Microsoft JDBC Driver and integrated authentication you need to run your builds on a [Windows Runner](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/windows-shared-runner-beta/)

In case you have to use Linu you can work it around using [JTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and connection string like:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_name:1433;databaseName=your-database;domain=your-domain;useNTLMv2=true;
```

and specify your username and password in the appropriate sections of the JDBC Connection Configuration.

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Comment: Just as you posted this I realized that this was likely the problem - Windows vs. Linux.  Thanks.